# Knative/Istio error: INTERNAL:inconsistent global dictionary versions used: mixer knows 221 words, caller knows 222

Tags: istio, knative

I'm getting this error on Google Kubernetes Engine when I try to call my Knative Endpoint:

`INTERNAL:inconsistent global dictionary versions used: mixer knows 221 words, caller knows 222`

A quick google search led to no one reporting any error like this before. I started reading the Istio code, but I'm at a total loss as to what this error means: https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/mixer/pkg/api/grpcServer.go#L87

I've gotten this error in a number of different contexts with a number of different versions of Knative, Istio and Kubernetes. Basically I'm looking for some sort of guidance as to what this error means so I can go about debugging it.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your version of istio,gke and knative? What version of knative You use? CloudRun, Knative Open-Source?

Comment: Knative 0.12.0, no cloud run. Istio 1.4.3,  GKE 1.15.7-gke.2

Comment: @jt97 Specifically getting this error trying to install the Cloud Endpoints GKE proxy on GKE: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/deploy-api-backend (Deploying it as a Knative service)

Comment: You need to provide more details as it's impossible to figure out what is causing issues. How was Knative deployed, step by step. How have you configured the GKE cluster. In order to reproduce the issue I need to setup copy of your exact env.

Comment: @alexwennerberg I've had this error with Istio 1.2.10 and Knative 0.12.1. The server got added with 222nd word in this commit https://github.com/istio/api/commit/a1b90298cbd53a7cd6659becb163a1d559e99daa and I saw it's available from 1.3.0. I've upgraded my Istio to 1.3.5 and see it works fine i.e., both caller and mixer has the same global dictionary. I no longer get this error and get my Knative KafkaSource invoke my service. Hope that helps.